# Best way to store 1000000 phone numbers in memory

Tags: java

What would be the best way to store `1000000` phone numbers in memory with the smallest memory footprint.

I was thinking of just using an array but im sure there has to be an better way

Comment: No need to bother about memory to store `1000000` element in `Java`. Just use `String` `Array` or `List`.

Comment: What do you use an array for? Each digit or a array of phone numbers. Furthermore `1m` is not that much.

Comment: There is no solution with a smaller footprint than an array. Perhaps, if you take advantage of the format of a phone number, you can try and use some kind of prefix tree, but you'd need to evaluate if the loss of memory due to extra references is worth it.

Comment: It was just a question i was asked so I thought i would see what more people think.

Comment: you could also compress the numbers into less bytes perhaps.  probably not worth the effort

Comment: There are millions of answers to this question which one would you like

Comment: Wouldnt storing it in a bitset have a smaller memory footprint

Comment: Consider a compression algorithm such as gzip.

Comment: Depends on the length of the phone number, but one could use an array of bits, with each bit representing whether the phone number exists or not.  For unique 7 digit phone numbers, you would need 10^7 bits, where 10^6 bits are set.

Answer (score 3):

The size of memory scales not significantly with the way you store the collection (!) of numbers, but more with how you actually store one phone number (as a string, or as an integer).

If you really want to reduce memory, try to store each phone number using an `long`.

For instance if you store phone numbers in an `ArrayList` you will get a maximum overhead of say `30%`, which is not that much. If you however store each phone number as a string, you will get an overhead of let's say `900%` compared to storing data using integers.

Comment: An `int` won't hold, for instance, a U.S. ten-digit phone #.

Comment: allright, `long` then. But still this will significantly reduce memory: a `long` is `8` bytes, but a string is `10*2=20 bytes`.

Comment: Agreed, `long` is more compact that storing them in a `String`.

Comment: With the answer I wanted to point out that one does not reduce the memory footprint significantly by questioning how to store `1M` of phone numbers, but should question more on how to store a single entity.

Comment: `int` would even be enough if you do a little bit fiddling, like using the first bit for determining if a `0` is leading, but there has to be a specification about what phone numbers could be stored.

Comment: @maxdev: not if you want to be able to store every phone number. Since there are estimated `6B` phone numbers and ints can only represent `4B` states. Since you don't know in advance which numbers will be added, you cannot compress a priori.

Comment: Yep, if it has to be generic, thats right.

Answer (score 1):

The array has the smallest memory footprint.

Comment: ...but it's also the least useful.

Comment: It depends on what do you want to use the data for...

Comment: "useful" in what meaning? Sure its less flexible to manage the data, but it has the lowest overhead.

Comment: @maxdev: The point of putting that much data in a reasonable data structure is the ability to query and search on it.  With an array, you're forced to do mostly exact searches in O(n) time every time.  Memory footprint be damned if you can't get your data in a reasonable manner.

Comment: @Makoto the point of putting that much data in such a structure was not stated, the only criteria was low overhead. Also, sorting the list and then using the binary search algorithm is as fast as you can get, except using something like a hash map (which again causes overhead).

Answer (score -1):

make an algorithm for phone number. pretty complex. if you can do it though, that would save a lot of memory.

Comment: Stating that compressing a phone number is "pretty complex" does not help. Also, it's not very complex if you know what number formats you'll have to expect - then its only a bit shifting excercise.